# Unable to execute native sql query

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

I am developing an application with Spring and hibernate. In the DAO class, I was trying to execute a native sql as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY unitprice ASC LIMIT 6 OFFSET 0
```

But the system throws an exception.

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:63)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:544)
com.dao.ProductDAO.listProducts(ProductDAO.java:15)
com.dataobjects.impl.ProductDoImpl.listProducts(ProductDoImpl.java:26)
com.action.ProductAction.showProducts(ProductAction.java:53)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

application-context.xml is show below

```
   <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
      p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
      p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
      p:url="${jdbc.url}"
      p:username="${jdbc.username}"
      p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

<!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
<!-- class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean"-->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource">
          <ref local="dataSource"/>
      </property>
     <property name="configLocation">
        <value>WEB-INF/classes/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property  name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
   </property>
    <!--    <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
               <value>com.pojo.Product</value>
               <value>com.pojo.User</value>
               <value>com.pojo.UserLogin</value>
            </list>
    </property> -->
     <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- User Bean definitions -->

<bean name="/logincheck" class="com.action.LoginAction">
    <property name="userDo" ref="userDo" />
</bean>
<bean id="userDo" class="com.dataobjects.impl.UserDoImpl" >
<property name="userDAO" ref="userDAO" />
</bean>
<bean id="userDAO" class="com.dao.UserDAO" >
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean name="/listproducts" class="com.action.ProductAction">
    <property name="productDo" ref="productDo" />
</bean>
<bean id="productDo" class="com.dataobjects.impl.ProductDoImpl" >
<property name="productDAO" ref="productDAO" />
</bean>
<bean id="productDAO" class="com.dao.ProductDAO" >
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

And DAO class is

```
public class ProductDAO extends HibernateDaoSupport{

public List listProducts(int startIndex, int incrementor) {
   org.hibernate.Session session = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    String queryString = "SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY unitprice ASC LIMIT 6 OFFSET 0";
    List list = null;
    try{
        session.beginTransaction();
        org.hibernate.Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
        list = query.list();
        session.getTransaction().commit();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return list;
}

public List getProductCount() {
    String queryString = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Product";
    return getHibernateTemplate().find(queryString);
}
}
```

Any thoughts to fix it up?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you havent started a transaction. You need to start a transaction even for select queries and close the transaction at the end.

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/SessionsAndTransactions

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I did change DAO class. Please see the modified source. But still it is not working.